# How to use an Object array as a key in hashmap

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I have an object array called `Position[]` that returns an array of Position objects. I would like to use this as my key for a hashmap for the following: `HashMap<Position[],Double> h = new HashMap<>();`

I understand that arrays have different hashcodes even if the elements are the same. So I went ahead and tried to override the equals and hashcode. This was my attempt:

```
public class Key {
    private Position p1;
    private Position p2;

    public Key(Position p1, Position p2){
      this.p1 = p1;
      this.p2 = p2
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
      if (!(object instanceof Key)) {
        return false;
      }

      Key newKey = (Key) object;
      return this.hashCode()== newKey.hashCode(); //bit of a hack way
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
      int result = 17;
      result = 31 * result + this.p1.hashCode();
      result = 31 * result + this.p2.hashCode();
      return result;
    }
  }
```

So I had to change my map to `HashMap<Key,Double>` However, when ever i go to get the value using the key is still returns null.

An example of what can be passed into they constructor of *Key* are `G2 G4` or `E4 E6` ETC.

How would I go about achieving this so that the comparisons actually work?

Thanks.

Comment: `this.hashCode()== newKey.hashCode()` ← That will fail eventually.  Just use a `List<Position>` instead of an array.  Arrays don’t have useful hash codes, but Lists are [guaranteed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#hashCode()) to have hash codes based on their elements’ hash codes.

Comment: If you cannot use `List` instead of arrays, you can get the correct hashcode using the utility class method [Arrays.hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: @VGR Is an ``ArrayList<Position>`` possible? or doe sit have to be ``List<Position>``

Comment: When you create an ArrayList, you can refer to it as a List, or a Collection, or an Iterable, or an Object.  It’s good practice to make variables and fields have a type of List or Collection rather than ArrayList, since there are many possible implementations of List (such as LinkedList and Arrays.asList) and you want to have the option of using them.  It’s not like you need your List to be an ArrayList in order to use its methods, after all.

Comment: @VGR so would this mean I won't need to override the ``equals`` and ``hashcode``?

Comment: Correct.  All List implementations in Java SE already implement those methods correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a special wrapper object to use `Position[]` as a key in a `Map`, using [`Arrays.deepEquals(Object[], Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) and [`Arrays.deepHashCode(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepHashCode(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) in the implementations of `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()`.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public final class PositionArrayKey {
    private final Position[] array;

    public PositionArrayKey(Position[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == this) return true;
        if (!(object instanceof PositionArrayKey)) return false;
        return Arrays.deepEquals(this.array, ((PositionArrayKey) object).array);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.deepHashCode(this.array);
    }
}
```

This enables storing `Position[]` array instances as keys in map, when wrapped. E.g.

```java
Map<PositionArrayKey, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(new PositionArrayKey(new Position[]{...}), ...);
Object value = map.get(new PositionArrayKey(new Position[]{...}), ...);
```

> (assuming that both of the `Position[]` arrays are deeply equal in this example)

Note that for large arrays, performance for invoking `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` may be slow. You can modify the above snippet to cache the result `Arrays.deepHashCode(this.array)` for larger arrays, if you find it necessary.

Comment: I think you mean "may be slow" rather than "may not be slow", yes?

Comment: @Steve Yes, was a typo. Fixed, thanks for pointing it out.